# Still getting KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY' in my Django Project having set up environment variables

Tags: django, python-3.x, windows, heroku

I created environment variables for my django project within my pipenv virtual envronment bin/activate (linux) or scripts\activate(windows) file , i made necessary changes in settings file as well as exiting and re activating the virtual environment but im still getting a keyerror (I'm working on a windows machine)

variables in settings.py

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ['EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD']
```

evnvironment variables in virtualenv\scripts\activate file

```
export SECRET_KEY= "mysecretkey"

export EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD= "mypassword"
```

error

```
File "C:\Users\Dell\.virtualenvs\team-272-SMES-Server-dSgdZ4Ig\lib\os.py", line 673, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

Comment: Try `set SECRET_KEY="mysecretkey"` on windows.

Comment: @Alasdair still getting the same error

Comment: I don't use Windows so don't really have any suggestions. Try typing `set` after activating the virtual environment - I think that should display your environment variables. You could also try running the `set`/`export` commands manually before running `manage.py`. That way you can figure out whether the issue is the actual commands, or that they are not being run when you activate the environment.

Comment: Add `SECRET_KEY=mysecretkey` before your command like `SECRET_KEY=mysecretkey python manage.py`

Comment: @JRajan that doesn't work

Comment: @Alasdair i tried using set command to view the environment variables on my system and i couldn't see my above stated variables listed so i had to set them manually which means django isn't looking for them in my virtual environment activate file but rather in system level variables, thanks for the info. I suggest you make that comment an answer

Comment: When your run the activate file, it can set environment variables which Django can read from the environment. Django doesn't ever look in the activate file.

Comment: As I said before, I don't use Windows, so I think it's better to let you or somebody else leave an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have "SECRET_KEY" in your os.environ

Use this code to check if you have "SECRET_KEY" there:

```
import os 
import pprint 

# Get the list of user's 
# environment variables 
env_var = os.environ 

# Print the list of user's 
# environment variables 
print("User's Environment variable:") 
pprint.pprint(dict(env_var), width = 1)
```

You are probably missing "SECRET_KEY" in the environment variable list. You can add a variable:

```
# importing os module  
import os 

# Add a new environment variable  
os.environ['GeeksForGeeks'] = 'www.geeksforgeeks.org'
```

[source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-environ-object/)

Comment: I got your point. I use heroku for my app, so I set my variables there, and I have a settings_local file that is for local development and the variables are hardcoded there. I am not sure if this helps

Comment: Ah, now I understand how it's useful to use a python file for local settings in development, if you set environment variables in production. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows server, I recommend creating a JSON (or YAML) file with all your database and app secrets. I personally prefer JSON, so an example of one is

```
{
"SECRET_KEY": "...",
"MYSQL_DBUSER": "jon"
"MYSQL_PW": "..."
...
}
```

Then in your `settings.py` you should add something like

```
import json

with open("config.json") as config:
    config = json.load(config)
```

Then to simply load in your project's secrets, index them by the variable name like

```
SECRET_KEY = config['SECRET_KEY']
```